# Python: elegant solution to transform the following string to a dictionary

Tags: python

I encountered a string input in the following format:

```
'1:[2,3],4:[1],3:[4],2:[4]'
```

How to transform it into the following format:

```
{1:[2,3],4:[1],3:[4],2:[4]}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where does this input come from?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Copied from python doc *"Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python literal or container display"*
- you can read more info here. https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

```
from ast import literal_eval

d = literal_eval('{1:[2,3],4:[1],3:[4],2:[4]}')

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{1: [2, 3], 4: [1], 3: [4], 2: [4]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some fun with regex :)

```py
import re

parse_re = r"(\d+):\[([^\]]*)\]"

raw_str = '1:[2,3],4:[1],3:[4],2:[4]'

res_dict = {}

for curr_match in re.finditer(parse_re, raw_str):
    dict_key, dict_val_str = curr_match.groups()
    dict_key = int(dict_key)
    dict_val = [int(item) for item in dict_val_str.split(',')]
    res_dict[dict_key] = dict_val
```

---

I'd like to dedicate this *hardcore fun* method to Derek Eden.

```py
import re

parse_re = r"(\d+):\[([^\]]*)\]"

raw_str = '1:[2,3],4:[1],3:[4],2:[4]'

match_groups = (curr_match.groups() for curr_match in re.finditer(parse_re, raw_str))

res_dict = {int(curr_key): [int(item) for item in curr_val.split(',')] for curr_key, curr_val in match_groups}
```

Comment: I think it's not really elegant comparing to previous answer.

Comment: @HùngNguyễn Eh, it was more for the fun of it, and to have a different solution.

Comment: nice Unique solution.

Comment: regex is always the best/funnest answer

Comment: @DerekEden see my edit ;)

Comment: now we're talkin